# fatal: ']' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ionic2

i am trying to Push my code up to the dashboard. but it shows the fatal error.

*git push ionic master*

The above command is not working...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238616/git-push-fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-fatal-could-n

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push: "fatal 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository - fatal Could not read from remote repository."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238616/git-push-fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-fatal-could-n)