# My project files are not getting pushed to GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a problem similar to the question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238616/git-push-fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-fatal-could-n/32238628) but when I try the solutions on my side it doesn't work.

I created a new project named "example1".
Then I create a repository on GitHub named "example1".

After committing all changes, I ran

```
git push origin master
```

and came across this message:

```
$ git push origin master
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com:Sidney-Dev: Name or service not 
known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then I added this command:

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com:Example-Dev/example1.git
```

And then checked:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@github.com:Sidney-Dev/laravelblog.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@github.com:Sidney-Dev/laravelblog.git (push)
```

But when I try to do git push again, I still come across the same errors as mentioned above.

How can I push my code to the GitHub repository?

Answer (score 1):

first, remove your origin:

`git remote remove origin`

then add it again...but without ssh://

`git remote add origin git@github.com:Example-Dev/example1.git`

You can copy the commands right from the gh initialization page.

Or you can read this: [git ssh protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_ssh_protocol)

I guess it expects a port after : when you use the URL scheme

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the ssh remote URL is either

```
git@github.com:Sidney-Dev/laravelblog.git
```

or

```
ssh://git@github.com/Sidney-Dev/laravelblog.git
```

Please note slash instead of colon.

Comment: @php So I first used git remote remove command...then used this:  git remote add origin git@github.com:Sidney-Dev/laravelblog.git. when I run "git push origin master" it says that my current branch is behind, but when I run "git pull remote master" or "git pull" it says that my baccess rights are not correct, which is the same error I was getting.

Comment: *current branch is behind* and *access rights are not correct* are different problems. Your initial problem with incorrect ssh URL syntax is now fixed, as for the other problems you better ask new questions.

Answer (score -1):

You may have to manually go to the github website and create the repository, then do git pull on your master branch and open the project through git bash.