# Trying to pull from github i get error remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, github

My server was working fine until yesterday
it was pulling fine.
today I run the command

```
>> git pull origin <branch>
```

I get a response: remote: Repository not found.
I run command

```
>> ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get response: Hi! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

```
>> I added ssh to my use and it has read and write ability
```

I even added config file like in here

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

still not working, and it'd be a mess if I create a new repo.

any ideas? is there something wrong with GitHub? why this might happen.

Comment: [Check your origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32238628/1790644) is correct and what is shown on GitHub.

Comment: yep , its correct and showing all branches correct as well -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your URL (`git remote -v`) is indeed git@github.com:/

- you should not need to use [SSH over the HTTPS port](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port)
- a `git ls-remote git@github.com:<you>/<yourRepo>` should work.

If not, check the case of the URL (it is case sensitive).

And try an HTTPS URL just for testing:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/<you>/<yourRepo>
```

That will ask for your credentials (GitHub username/password)

Comment: i did that, it helped a lot thanks, but figured out that my github account was revoked from permissions for that repo, so i had to reconfigure it.
btw where do you find those commands