# Git - 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git

I am working on a project called "**wonaco**". In this folder, from **locally**, I have pulled the master branch and created a new dev branch and **checkout** to that dev branch.

Now, I run this command:

```
git add .
git commit -m "First Commit"
git push origin dev
```

but I got the notice:

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could
> not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

I need to push my code to the **dev** branch.

Comment: did you set up a remote? Try `git remote` and post the output

Comment: output is empty

Comment: Did you "make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists"?

Comment: Don't forget to start ssh-agent and add your keys to your github-account. I voted to close the question since there are many suggestions to your question you can investigate first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git push: "fatal 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository - fatal Could not read from remote repository."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238616/git-push-fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-fatal-could-n)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't set up a remote.

run `git remote add origin <URL to remote repo>`, then try to push again.

Comment: I got this notice : `Writing objects: 100% (14545/14545), 25.47 MiB | 29.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 14545 (delta 4300), reused 12575 (delta 4176)
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
`

Comment: @Shibbir This is a separate issue, most likely due to files too large and remote closing the connection prematurely. You'll find a couple of questions in SO by searching "the remote end hung up unexpectedly". Please accept the answer if this solved your issue