# Push on GIT and Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

In my desktop, I have a folder named azerty, into this folder I have a file named `index.html`.
Into this file, I wrote `<h1>test</h1>`.

[image]

On Bitbucket, I have to create my repository. I named this repository like the name of the folder which is on my desktop, so `azerty`.

[image]

My repository is created

[image]

Now, I open GIT bash.

Here are my steps:

```
1- git init 
2- git clone https://Geek8006@bitbucket.org/Geek8006/azerty.git
3- git status
```

[image]

I don't understand why, I have a new folder `azerty` into my folder `azerty` (in my desktop)?

[image]

Then...

```
4- git add . 
5- git status 
6- git commit -m "test"
```

[image]

When I do the last step:

```
7- git push origin master
```

[image]

I have this error message

```
$ git push origin master
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In summary, I have 2 problems:

1- Why I have a new folder `azerty` into my folder `azerty` in my desktop ?

2- There are several subjects on the

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

like here -> [Git push: "fatal 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository - fatal Could not read from remote repository."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238616/git-push-fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-fatal-could-n)

But, it does not work.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Whilst helpful context, please don't include images of text in questions, _just put the text_. It's easier to read, and doesn't prevent visually impaired readers from seeing the question.

Comment: @AD7six: Ah! Sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to clone: you can add to your local repopsitory a reference to your new remote repository:

```
cd C:\path\to\my\repo
git remote add https://url/new/repo
git push -u origin main
```

That way, you keep your existing local repository, and add it a remote origin for you to push your content.

Make sure to delete your nested clone first.

Comment: This way, the nested repository is still committed in the outer repository. I don't think that @joel intended to have a nested repository that points to the same remote.

Comment: @Matt I would delete the nested clone first indeed.

Comment: I think that OP did not realize that there is a nested clone.

Comment: @Orace Yes, but no need to restart from scratch: delete the nested folder, add the remote, and push.

Comment: `give a man a fish and you feed him for a day ...`. You are right. As I guess OP is a newbie in git, I think it's also good to show OP the correct way to do it from the start point not the _current_ mess OP is now. Anyway it's better to show both and our answers are complementary on this point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations.

Answer (score 3):

When you cloned your repository, Git cloned it into a new folder `azerty` inside the directory that you already initialised as another Git repository. You should use either `git clone` or `git init` (and add a remote later) but not both.

So now you have an initialised repository without a remote which is why you get the error that `origin` is not know. And you have a cloned repository (with a remote) inside the `azerty` folder.

I recommend that you just delete both local repositories and start from scratch. You can specify the directory that a repository should get cloned into by passing this as an argument to git clone. To use the current directory, simply pass a `.`.

```
rm -rf ./.git                     # remove the .git folder
rm -rf ./azerty                   # remove the nested repository
git clone <repository> .          # clone into current directory
git add index.html
git commit -m "Add index.html"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Matt.

Answer (score 3):

### Problem analysis

With those two commands:

1. `git init`
2. `git clone https://example.com/azerty.git`

You are creating two git repository.

- The first one (I will call it **A**), created with the [init](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) command.

  - Is empty
  - Has his root in the current directory
  - Has no origin
- The second one (I will call it **B**), created with the [clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) command.

  - Is a clone of a distant repository
  - Has an origin (the distant repository)
  - Has his root located in a new directory named `azerty` created in the current directory. **That explain why you have a new `azerty` directory.**

Git warn you explicitly about that (yellow hint)

> you've added another git repository inside your current repository

Since it has been created with `init`, **A** doesn't have an origin.

When you try to `push` you are in the root directory of **A** so you are trying to `push` **A**. Since **A** doesn't have an origin, the `push` fail.

### Solution

Restart from scratch:

- Save your important files in a temporary folder.
- Use `git clone` where you want the `azerty` folder to appear.
- `move` your files into the `azerty` folder (or any sub folder).
- Use:

  - `git add .`
  - `git commit`
  - `git push`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanations. It's ok. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
git remote -v //To check if anything is there in origin
```

If there is nothing then do

```
git remote add origin https://Geek8006@bitbucket.org/Geek8006/azerty.git


git remote -v //To check again if it is listed
```

After this, you can commit and push.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. My problem is solved! Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

The git init command creates a new Git repository. It can be used to convert an existing, unversioned project to a Git repository or initialize a new, empty repository.

Please visit for reference [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init#:%7E:text=The%20git%20init%20command%20creates,run%20in%20a%20new%20project.).

**Solution 2:**

That error occurred because it's remote origin is not set.
In order to set the origin you need to run this command. **[refer dummy example]**

```
git remote add origin https://repositoryurlpath.git
```

*Dummy example*

```
git add .
git commit -m "Your commit message"
git remote add origin https://repositoryurlpath.git
git push origin master
```

**Tips ahead**

**Check if the remote origin is set**

git remote -v

**Reset the remote origin**

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://repositoryurlpath.git
```