# git returns an error "does not appear to be a git repository" and "Could not read from remote repository"

Tags: git, nas

Good afternoon.
I lifted git to an ubuntu server that is installed on a virtual machine. When sending a file to git, I get an error (attached screenshot). Although everything is set according to "https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server " manual. Tell me how to fix it.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSuhW.png)

When interacting with github, everything is ok.

I will immediately answer the question why do I need git on a virtual machine, I have a Synology NAS at work on which git is also installed and configured. But again, when I try to contact him, I got the same error.
Client git - Sourcetree

Everything is also configured on my computer.
[my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KwBg.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=does+not+appear+to+be+a+git+repository+could+not+read+from+remote+repository

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32238616/12320578) answer your question?