# I'm trying to do a git fetch. However, I'm receiving an error "remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository not found

Tags: flutter, github

I've created a private repo in Github. But when i perform `git fetch`, it shows me an error of 'remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository not found.'  I am a collaborator and an owner of the repo in GitHub. I'm new to GitHub and have no idea what I can do to solve this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

I've tried `git remote add origin`. When I type in `git remote, it shows me 'origin'.

Answer (score 1):

This type of question should really be posted on SuperUser instead. But, since it's here, I'll respond here.

I'm assuming you've cloned the repository locally to your machine. If not, do `git clone <repo URL>`.

Further, `git` can't see private repos unless you have a public ssh key added to your Github account and the corresponding private key is on the machine that you're issuing the `git fetch` command.

To generate an ssh key, simply run `ssh-keygen` from a terminal in any directory. Accept the default location for the key and supply a passphrase if you wish. Then, copy the contents of the resulting `id_rsa.pub`. On Github, go to your "Settings" and go to "SSH and GPG keys". Then click "Add SSH key" and paste the public key contents there. Once you've added it to Github, `git` will be able to see your private repos.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but even when i do git clone, the same error appears saying remote: Repository not found. When I did git remote add origin however, it shows "error: remote origin already exists." Hence why I'm confused

Comment: @haloPri Have you added an SSH key to your account?

Comment: yep I tried adding SSH key but still no difference.

Comment: @haloPri See if the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32238616/git-push-fatal-origin-does-not-appear-to-be-a-git-repository-fatal-could-n?rq=1) get you in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

Try `git remote add origin <URL>` per the [git remote examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#_examples)

Comment: Hi there, I've done this but it shows me "error: remote origin already exists.". But when i try to even do git clone, it shows me  remote: Repository not found.

Comment: do `git remote rm origin` and then `git remote add <URL>`